# html and php update system not working

Tags: php, html, sql

I am working on a site for my students at school, which will make them want to learn and earn xp points, level up... but when they level up they receive an armer of choice, which in my database is known as armer_students. What I want have is an update system which contains the sa_id (student id) and the armer_id, the system will be updating the armer_id.
Everything is printing correctly on my page, but when i click update on the update button and refresh the page, nothing has changed...

```
<?php 

include 'db_functions.php';


$rows = db_select("SELECT * FROM armer_students");
if($rows === false) {
    $error = db_error();
    // Handle error - inform administrator, log to file, show error page, etc.
}





if(isset($_POST['update'])) {

         // Quote and escape form submitted values
  $sa_id = $_POST['sa_id'];
  $armer_id = $_POST['armer_id'];

// Insert the values into the database
$sql = "UPDATE students SET armer_id= ".$armer_id ." WHERE sa_id=".$sa_id;
$result = db_query($sql);

    }


?>

<html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" >

   </head>

   <body>
    <?php include 'menu.php'; ?>        
   <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>armer id</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>

<?php foreach($rows as $row) :?>
  <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['sa_id'] ;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['armer_id'] ;?></td>



   </tr>
<?php endforeach ;?>


  </table>
   <hr />

               <tr>
                     <td width = "100">sa_id</td>
                     <td><input name = "sa_id" type = "number" id = "sa_id"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td width = "100">armer_id</td>
                     <td><input name = "armer_id" type = "number" id = "armer_id"></td>
                  </tr>



                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td>
                           <input name = "update" type = "submit" id = "update" value = "Update">
                        </td>
                     </tr>

                  </table>
               </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks very much :-)

Comment: What is the status of all your past questions? If any have been solved, it'd be best to mark them off as being solved.

Comment: i had to solve them myself in the end but I will follow yore advise and do that. @Fred-ii-

Comment: FYI: Stack lets you post your own answer, which you can accept when it lets you.

Comment: Ok, and how do you mark them as solved @Fred-ii-

Comment: Great thanks @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome. See if there's anything that yields from using error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and checking for errors on the query with `mysqli_error($Your_Connection)`. Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and use `mysqli_affected_rows($Your_Connection)`. Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php to check for truthness.

Comment: A good function to use when debugging code like this i to use a function like `mysqli_affected_rows`. Which checks how many rows were affected in your last query. I'd recommend putting it after you've updated the database (in your if that checks for 'update').

EDIT: mysqli_error() like Fred mentioned won't be showing any error messages if your query simply didn't update anything, I.e 0 rows affected.

Comment: Great thanks for the advise @Fred-ii- , i will look into it, i am not an experienced coder (haven't done my GCSE's yet) so i am really great full! :-)

Comment: and @LinusJuhlin

Comment: Anytime. Also, using a hidden input with a value for the said row is what should be used. These Q&A's will help https://stackoverflow.com/q/17079170/1415724 --- https://stackoverflow.com/q/36306129/1415724 --- https://stackoverflow.com/q/20804505/1415724

Comment: Great these all look vey helpful @Fred-ii-  :-)